# Picard theorem for $u' = \sqrt{\lvert u^2 -1 \rvert}$ if we know $ u(\pi / 2)= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Problem: can we apply Picard theorem for $$u' = \sqrt{\lvert u^2 -1 \rvert}$$ if $$
u(\pi / 2)= 0$$
[$u$ is a function of a variable $x$ so $u = u(x)$]
My attempt:

Well, what I need to know is whether the function $f(x,u) = \sqrt{\lvert u^2 -1 \rvert} $ is Lipshitz continuous when observing only the second variable: u, on some rectangle $(\pi/2 - \delta,\pi/2 + \delta)\times(1- \epsilon,1 + \epsilon)$.

I'm however uncertaion whether this holds. I would say that if $\epsilon \geq 1$ the function is definitely not Lipshitz contiuous on the second variable, but I'm really not sure how to prove that it is or isn't if $\epsilon > 1$, it seems to me it's supposed to be, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Comment: What about computing $\partial f/\partial u$ and checking if it is bounded?

Comment: @Mattos but I don't think you can compute it at any point (x,1) ? (because of the absolute value function..)

Comment: The Picard theorem is a local one, so you don't need to bother about $\epsilon\ge1$. Here, the assumptions are not satisfied at $(x,-1)$ and at $(x,1)$ for any real $x$. Further, notice that $u(x)=\sin{x}$ for $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Do you see what happens at $x=\pm\pi/2$?